# iOS basic memory management

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, memory-management

I'm reading through the Big Nerd Ranch book on iOS programming and I had a question about the Hypnotime program they create in chapter 7.

At some point, they implement the following method:

```
- (void)showCurrentTime:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;

    if (!formatter) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    }

    [timeLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:now]];

}
```

My question is about `NSDateFormatter *formatter`. The formatter gets created with `alloc` and `init`. I always learnt that anything with `alloc` needs to be released somewhere, right? When `formatter` gets passed to `timeLabel`, doesn't `timeLabel` send `retain`to it? And can't (shouldn't?) I subsequently release `formatter`?

I browsed through the code on the next couple of pages and I can't find any release message anywhere, except for a `release` being send to `timeLabel` in `dealloc`.

Am I mixing things up here? Is there a reason why `formatter` shouldn't be released by me? I want to be a good memory citizen. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They declared the formatter as static so the intention is to keep the formatter alive for the entire lifetime of the application. This would be for performance reasons and may be a pre-mature optimization so do not take this as a best practice in future development of your own.

```
//static (even in a method) will allow formatter to live during entire app lifecycle
static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;

//Check if formatter has been set (this is not thread safe)
if (!formatter) {
    //Set it once and forget it, it wont be a leak, and it wont ever be released
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If it is kept alive for the entire lifetime of the application, does that mean I should release it in dealloc or not release it at all? A bit confused about this, to be honest.

Comment: No it is not intended to be released and it will not create a memory leak unless assign formatter again with out releasing it first. That is why there is an if check.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the `static` keyword the `formatter` will stay available until next time the method is called, as a global variable - well, without being *global*

See wikipedia entry about [static](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The wiki entry cleared some things about `static` up :)

Answer (score 1):

setText just gets a string (not the formatter itself), so the formatter is not retained. My bet is that they use the formatter somewhere else in the controller and so it get released in dealloc

Comment: don't mind the dealloc part, didn't see it was static, but the first part remains true